# How to return most popular items in a table, but where each item is unique?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to figure out a tricky Django query that I hope you can help with. I have this model:

```
class ActiveVenue(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue)

class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

In my app there are many Events and each event can have multiple active venues, hence my current data structure. I would prefer if your solution is not "change your model to foo" as this is already a deployed site and I would like to keep the current model structure.

I want to write a query that returns the most popular venues but in which a venue is only counted once for each user. As an example, if I have one user with four events and they use the same venue every time, I only want to count that venue once when determining the most popular venues.

To illustrate this, imagine this is my data:

```
event: A    user: bob   venue: The Hill
event: B    user: bob   venue: The Hill
event: C    user: bob   venue: The Hill
event: D    user: jane   venue: The Oaks
event: E    user: sarah   venue: The Pound
event: F    user: david   venue: The Pound
event: G    user: ron   venue: The Oaks
event: H    user: erica   venue: The Oaks
```

Here the popular order would be:

```
1. The Oaks
2. The Pound
3. The Hill
```

Any suggestions how I write a query to do this that works on both postgres and sqlite (in other words, doesn't rely on `distinct()` (not supported in sqlite))?

Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure `disctinct` should work in sqlite. As per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct, you can't specify parameters in sqlite, but the function should work in general.

Comment: I don't think you can do this using Django ORM considering the user restriction. For this it seems you will have to write some manual SQL.

Comment: @miki725 I agree, if it's abstracted into a function that returns a collection it could defer to the ORM in situations where distinct() is supported and manual SQL when it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
from collections import Counter 
results = Counter([vid for vid, eid in ActiveVenue.objects.values_list("venue_id", "event_id").distinct()]
```

Comment: +1, collections.Counter is very high quality and is designed for just this purpose. After you have the above code, something like `results.most_common(3)` should give you the answer you're looking for, sorted nicely and everything.

Comment: While this works, I think we should avoid iterating whole querysets in Python. Iterate only after taking a slice (paginate). A query set can be extremely large and a view can take a long time to respond if we iterate over a raw queryset without slicing it first.

Answer (score 0):

See if something like this works

```
ActiveVenue.objects.all().annotate(score=Count('event__user', distinct=True)).order_by('-score')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my version (finish test):

**models.py**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def ranking(self):
        count=0
        actives = ActiveVenue.objects.filter(
            venue__name=self.name).values(
            'event__user__username', 'venue__name').distinct()
        for active in actives:
            count += 1
        return count
```

**views.py**

```
def getRanking( anObject ):
    return anObject.ranking()

def myview(request):
    venues = list(Venue.objects.filter())
    venues.sort(key=getRanking, reverse=True)
    return render(request,'page.html',{'venues': venues})
```

**templates**

```
{% for venue in venues %}
    {{forloop.counter}}. {{venue}}<br/>
{% endfor %}
```

**Output:**

1. The Oaks
2. The Pound
3. The Hill

Comment: Again, this loads everything into memory and sort the whole table in memory. Not a good practice. If something is not achievable by a SQL query then the schema should be denormalized a bit to make it possible instead of loading everything and sorting/filtering in framework code.

Comment: @OwaisLone this will only sort the active venues and by year as he required but I didn't put that in the filter.

Comment: I'm not saying it work for Jono. Really depends on how many ActiveVenues he's going to have. Just pointing out a good practice.

Comment: @OwaisLone OK I know it's not a better answer. But this is what I have work just solving his problem. Maybe there is a way to refactor this code. I try the other answers here before I post my answer a while ago, and I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem. First, here is a query that will grab the Venue ids and the scores corresponding to the related users.

```
testquery = ActiveVenue.objects.values("venue").annotate(score=Count("event__user", distinct=True)).order_by("-score")
```

Result

```
[{'score': 3, 'venue': 2}, {'score': 2, 'venue': 3}, {'score': 1, 'venue': 1}]
```

Next, the venue ids will be placed in a new list.

```
query_ids = [item["venue"] for item in testquery]
[2, 3, 1]
```

Next, the corresponding Venue objects have to be obtained.

```
tempresult = Venue.objects.filter(id__in=query_ids)
[<Venue: The Hill>, <Venue: The Oaks>, <Venue: The Pound>
```

Finally, a list comprehension will be performed to re-order the Venue objects based on the scores obtained earlier.

```
result = [venue for venue_id in query_ids for venue in tempresult if venue_id == venue.id]
[<Venue: The Oaks>, <Venue: The Pound>, <Venue: The Hill>]
```

This gives the proper result based on the test data.